# Chi squared distribution question type I can't do

Tags: statistics

[image]

Please please I have been doing exam papers and preparing for my exam but I always can't do these type of questions in statistics, after I get to know how to do once il be able to do these types which are common on my papers. Pleasee don't ask me what I did because I'm stunned at this question, but I do know upto that we have to use chi squared distribution but I am unable to find the expected values, I don't know actually because they do not tell the expectation. Please help me.

Comment: Actually, this seems more like an ANOVA : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANOVA

Comment: But even the marking scheme agrees with that it's a chi squared testing, ummm maybe it's like an ANOVA too, but ANOVA isn't in the syllabus so it's not taught to us so we can't use.

Comment: So since we haven't been taught that also means I dono anything about ANOVA or neither can we use it.

Comment: The reason I think this is an ANOVA is that we are doing a comparison of means. When we are comparing just 2 means, it is a straightforward t-test, but for 3-or-more, to the best of my knowledge, it is an ANOVA.

Comment: You may want to post this in Statistics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard 3x2 contingency table and the question is whether there is an association between area and preference, so that you can test this hypothesis using a simple chi-square test. Expected values for each cell are calculated as the product of the total of the row and the total of the column, divided by the total of the whole table. You can also rapidly perform this test online.